# Does generating a CSR through IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 always create a new private key?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, iis-7.5, private-key, csr

Generating a CSR for a Windows 2008 R2 server and need to ensure that the private key used for the CSR is new.

I have used OpenSSL before to create my own self-signed certs for testing and if I remember correctly, I was able to specify a private key to use.

In IIS Server Certificates, I am never asked to generate nor pick a private key.

So, does generating a CSR on a Windows-based server always create a new private key for it?  If not, how do I ensure a new private key is made/used?

Comment: You mean *private* key?

Comment: Yes, thanks, editing now.  I'm a developer before a sysadmin, so primary key just came out of my head first.  :)

Comment: Generating a CSR, or generating a cert?  What, exactly are you doing, and how are you doing it?  (It makes a difference.)

Comment: I am generating a CSR that will be given to a CA to create the cert.  This is being done through IIS and it's Server Certificates interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

The "Create Certificate Request" Wizard automatically generates a new key pair.

> In IIS Server Certificates, I am never asked to generate nor pick a
>   private key.

This is actually not true - the wizard is just not super obvious about it.

When you've entered the identity information (Common Name, Locality, Organization etc.) and hit "Next", the second screen asks for 2 things:

1. A Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP)
2. A Bit-length

[image]

Choosing the default CSP - the Microsoft RSA SChannel CSP - and a Bit Length of 2048 would be the Windows equivalent to:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048
```

---

### Anatomy of a Signing Request

The CSR itself can be thought of as having 3 "parts":

1. Identity information in clear text (CN, Locality, Org. etc.)

   - This is simply strings, the signatory (the CA) can alter those at will
2. The Public Key

   - You'll need the corresponding private key on your server
3. Optional extension fields

   - Still just clear text information

The Issuer reviews the information in the signing request, an may alter the contents of both (1) and (3).
The Issuer then uses it's CA *private key* to encrypt the requesters public key (2).

When the final Certificate is issued it contains:

1. Identity information in clear text (CN, Locality, Org. etc.)

   - Now with Issuer information added
2. The Public Key

   - Still the same as above
3. Optional extension fields

   - Now maybe with Issuer extension fields
4. **A Signature blob**

   - This is the Public key signed with the CA's private key

Now, the next time a client get's your certificate presented, it can use the Issuer CA's *public key* to decrypt the signature blob (4) and compare it to the public key in the certificate